# Locust: Web Interface from AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, locust

I just started using Locust, installed on a AWS instance and it is working fine. But I am unable to get to the web interface. Port 8089 is open in the AWS security group.

http://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8089 is not working for me.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried with public ip address ? and in the server check port 8089 is open or not : netstat -anpl | grep 8089

Comment: That is hard to do, because when I start Locust the terminal is in use. Cannot run a second command...

Comment: you can run Locust in daemon : $xxxxx &  then run the second command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to run Locust on AWS is Elastic Beanstalk, follow these steps: https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx351HCZ9D1RQ84/Using-Locust-on-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-for-Distributed-Load-Generation-and-Testin